# Input text into a variable

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('.raffle_information > div:eq(0)').append('<input type="text" name="name">');
```

I made this small input box and I want to store the text that user types into a variable. How do I do that?

Comment: you can write a change event for that

Comment: Do you mean into the value attribute?

Comment: No, just something like var text = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

It will keep the value of the variable always updated whenever the user changes the value in the field.

```
var myTextVal;
$('<input type="text" name="name">').appendTo('.raffle_information > div:eq(0)').on('keyup', function(){
   myTextVal = $(this).val();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vUVdm/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, though currently untested:

```
var val;
$('.raffle_information > div:eq(0)').append('<input type="text" name="name">').on('change', 'input[name="name"]', function(){
    val = this.value;
});
```

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).